# Send email out after new employee registered by overriding Devise Registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Rails 4.2 
Devise

I would like to send out a welcome email to newly registered employees.

I have the following overridden Devise Registrations Controller:

```
class Employees::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout 'dashboard', only: [:new]
  # Only allow admin employees to add new employees
  before_action :authenticate_employee!, :redirect_unless_admin,  only: [:new, :create]

  # Removes the already logged in issue with Devise
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication 

  def create
   super
   EmployeeMailer.welcome_email(resource).deliver_now if resource.valid?
  end


  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:employee).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :paypal_email, :mobile, :skype_id, :address,:province_state, :country, :postal_code, :bachelor_degree, :os, :status, role_ids: [])
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:employee).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :paypal_email, :mobile, :skype_id, :address, :province_state, :country, :postal_code, :bachelor_degree, :os, :status, role_ids: [])
  end

  def redirect_unless_admin
    unless current_employee && current_employee.is_super_admin?
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "Only authorized ProvenWord Employees are permitted to register new employees."
    end
  end

   def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    true
  end
end
```

This works, however I don't think its correct as I have to test if the resource is valid otherwise the system tries to send out emails even for submissions with invalid data.

Is this the correct way of doing this or how should I make sure only a resource that is saved to the database will be used to send out an email?

Comment: Maybe you want to do "if resource.persisted?" or "unless resource.new_record?" since sometimes a valid object might not be saved if you have a before_save method that returned false for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send email to the newly registered employees by creating a callback method **"after_create"** in employee model

```
after_create :send_welcome_email

def send_welcome_email
  EmployeeMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_now
end
```

Comment: That seems the best solution. Thanks Andolasoft.